# Even out existing loop cuts

Tags: edges, loop

How do I even out **existing** loop cuts?
I know about the LoopTools "Space" tool, but it requires pretty much manual selection of horizontal edges, "Select similar" doesn't select the ones I need.

[image: Mesh example]

Answer (score 3):

Using *Select > Select loops > Select Rings* on a <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> selected edge selects all similar edges.

LoopTools' *Space* works just fine on those.

[image].